# CFWheels App goes to directory structure instead

Tags: iis, coldfusion, iis-8, cfwheels, coldfusion-11

I just added a CFwheels site to my IIS 8 and instead of going to the actual page is showing the directory structure on the browser. Any hints on what I should check?

Comment: Check the connecter installer. It seems like CF is not installed correctly.

Comment: It's an AMI from Amazon so you can't really trust it that much I guess. I will check again thanks

Comment: @MarkAKruger I created a test page which only dumps the cgi struct and it's working just fine. Is there any issue between CFWheels and  CF11?

Comment: Sounds like, "Default document" is not working. Try setting it up at "Server" & "Site" level.

Comment: @AnitKumar be more specific please

Comment: @MarkAKruger just responded, what I was about to.Thanks Mark.

Comment: Anit... no problem. I'm trying to catch up to Ray on points :D

Comment: You will surely, soon :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geo,

Your problem is the default document settings as Anit has suggested. In the IIS8 control pannel look for a cpl called "default document". It will show a list of documents that are served by "Default" so that when you navigate to something.com/home it actually serves up something.com/home/index.cfm (as an example).

Make sure you add your desired default document to the list. You can aslo do this in the web.config file:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <defaultDocument enabled="true">
         <files>
            <add value="index.cfm" />
         </files>
      </defaultDocument>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

You are correct I think that if it is an Adobe AMI it should have such a setting by default - but perhaps you are not using a standard default doc.

You probably want to disable directory browsing as well - that's also a cpl I think.